# RTClib now() within while loop does not update

Tags: rtc

I ran into this while trying to make a battery monitor and wondered where I went wrong. Using `RTClib` available in the Arduino IDE or from [adafruit github](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib), I ran into problems when trying to call `now` within a `while` loop inside of `loop`.  Here is a simple example:

```
#include "RTClib.h"

#define ledPIN 13

RTC_PCF8523 rtc;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(ledPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial) {/* wait for Serial */}
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.start();
  digitalWrite(ledPIN, HIGH);
 }

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char fmt[] = "YYYY/MM/DD-hh:mm:ss\n";
  while (millis() < 60000){
    Serial.println((rtc.now()).toString(fmt));
    delay(5000); 
  }
  Serial.println("Finished");
  digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);
  while(1) { /* do nothing forever */ }
}
```

The output of this little test will be the same time repeated every 5ish seconds.  If it matters I am using a Feather M0 with the FeatherLogger that has an RTC on it.  Changing this `loop` function to this:

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char fmt[] = "YYYY/MM/DD-hh:mm:ss\n";
  if (millis() < 60000){
    Serial.println((rtc.now()).toString(fmt));
    delay(5000); 
  } else {
    Serial.println("Finished");
    digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);
    while(1) { /* do nothing forever */ }
  }
}
```

shows that `now` does in fact update the time every 5ish seconds.  I looked at the code for `now` and it appears to do very basic i2c commands to get the time and report it back.  The only thing I can think of is that the compiler created a (not so) temporary `DateTime` object for me within the `while` loop and the RTC library does not provide a convenient constructor or operator to overwrite the existing object.

I tested my theory with this

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char fmt[] = "YYYY/MM/DD-hh:mm:ss\n";
  while (millis() < 60000){
    DateTime t1 = rtc.now();
    Serial.println(t1.toString(fmt));
    delay(5000); 
  }
  Serial.println("Finished");
  digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);
  while(1) { /* do nothing forever */ }
}
```

But again, the time did not change so clearly I don't understand what's happening here.  Why doesn't the rtc `now` function work as intended within a `while` loop inside the `loop` function?

Comment: `if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    Serial.flush();
    abort();
  }` can you add this part to your code to check whether it is giving any error or not

Comment: You have also not added the date and time in your code. Before going forward can you check whether the example code is working or not

Comment: Try changing your loop to `while (millis() < 60000){  volatile DateTime time = rtc.now(); Serial.println(time.toString(fmt)); delay(5000);   }` If this works, your theory about a wrong compiler optimization is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation of `DateTime::toString()`](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_date_time.html#a3753bf2ae254315a56f7ee38ff0b188b):

> The *buffer* parameter should be initialized by the caller with a
> string specifying the requested format. This format string may contain
> any of the following specifiers: [...] The specifiers within *buffer*
> will be overwritten with the appropriate values from the `DateTime`.
> Any characters not belonging to one of the above specifiers are left
> as-is.

The important thing to realize is that the `buffer` parameter is used
**both** as input (for the format description) and as output (for the
formatted date and time). You initialize it with a format description
(`"YYYY/MM/DD-hh:mm:ss\n"`). Then, after the first call to `toString()`,
the same buffer contains the formatted date and time. It does **not**
contain the format description anymore. On the second call to
`toString()`, as per the rule “*Any characters not belonging to one of
the above specifiers are left as-is*”, the buffer is not modified.

**Solution**: Put the buffer initialization within the same `while` loop
as the call to `toString()`.

Comment: As usual, reading the documentation would have saved the OP a lot of time... ;-) +1